# For any $a \in \mathbb R$ and any $n \in \mathbb N^+$ there exists $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $|a-q|< \frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers, natural-numbers

For any $a \in \mathbb R$ and any $n \in \mathbb N^+$ there exists $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that 
$|a-q|< \frac{1}{n}$.

I think i can prove this is false, let $a=2,n=2,q=1/2$
so $|2-\frac{1}{2}|< \frac{1}{2}$ which is wrong. Is there a formal way to prove this?

Comment: That is not how you show this statement to be false.

Comment: To expound a bit, let's say that wherever you see "for any", you get to pick the numbers. And where it says "there exists", I have to find a number that makes the inequality true. You picked $2,2$. I pick $7/8$.

Comment: As he pointed out, you misunderstand the logic. This result comes from the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the theorem says "there exists", which means that providing one counterexample doesn't mean that no such $q$ exists.
To solve the problem, consider $k=\lfloor na\rfloor$ and let $q=\frac{k}{n}$. Then
$$
|a-\frac{k}{n}|=|\frac{na-\lfloor na\rfloor}{n}|<\frac{1}{n}
$$